# Excel 2011 on OSX always opens on same monitor

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, microsoft-excel-2011, osx-spaces, mission-control

I am running OSX and I have 3 monitors. In Mission Control, I have all 3 monitors to be their own Space. So each monitor has a toolbar at the top. Only one monitor has my dock on it (obviously). I will call that my primary monitor.

Every time I open Excel, via opening the application on the dock, or starting it from Applications folder, or double-clicking an Excel file, the Excel window ALWAYS opens on my primary monitor. I never ever opens anywhere else.

Even if I double-click an Excel file on a different monitor, it opens back on the primary monitor. Every time.

Even if I open an Excel window, then move it to a different monitor, THEN open a different file or ever create a new file, the new window opens back on the primary monitor. I would have expected it open in the current monitor where I am currently working...

Is is possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Option Click or LONG click the icon on your dock, select **Options** then choose the display to always **Assign To**.

Hope this helps!

[image: Dock Options]